# Filtering Optionals

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I am using [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-filter-stream-of-optional), but when I try the below the IDE states"

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Is not `Optional.isPresent()` a `static` method?

```
public interface SubscriberRepo extends JpaRepository<Subscriber,Long> {
    Stream<Subscriber> findAllByShortName(String shortName);
}

public int exists(Subscriber subscriber) {
        try (Stream<Subscriber> subscriber1_ = subRepo.findAllByShortName(subscriber.getShortName().trim().toUpperCase(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))) {
            List<Subscriber> subscribers = subscriber1_
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .filter(s -> subscriber.getEnabled())
                .filter(s -> !subscriber.getLocked())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Below is another way I tried it by returning just a `List<Subscriber>` but I can't seem to "get at" the `Subscriber`s as the error is:

> Required type `List<Subscriber>` provided `List<List<Subscriber>>`

How can I safely get at the Subscribers and filter them individually into a list?

```
List<Subscriber> subscriber1 = subRepo.findAllByShortName(subscriber.getShortName().trim().toUpperCase(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
List<Subscriber> subscriber1_ = Stream.of(subscriber1)
            .filter(s-> subscriber.getEnabled())
            .filter(s-> !subscriber.getLocked())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Optional.isPresent()` isn't static.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html  Try replacing it with something like `x->x.isPresent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to explain:

1. The `filter` method comes from `Stream<Subscriber>` therefore it expects `Predicate<Subscriber>`. If, however, the Stream type would be `Stream<Optional<Subscriber>>` such `filter(Optional::isPresent)` construct would be possible since it would basically mean:

   ```
   .filter(o -> o.isPresent())
   ```
2. `Optional#isPresent` is an instance method, not a `static` one. If your intention is:

   ```
   .filter(subscriber -> Optional.ofNullabe(subscriber).isPresent())
   ```

   ... it brings no real benefit and is better to use rather:

   ```
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   ```
3. Since the Stream is `Stream<Subscriber` and you don't create an `Optional` from `Subcriber`, the `.map(Optional::get)` call can be omitted. The folwing construct would make sense again only and only if the Stream would be of `Stream<Optional<Subscriber>>` from the DAO call.

   ```
   List<Subscriber> subscribers = subscriber1_
           .filter(Optional::isPresent)
           .map(Optional::get)
           ...
   ```

Comment: Hi
I thought the all collection queries from a repository are of the type Collection<Optonal<Object>> and taking the Stream of that as Stream<Subscriber> should give me a Stream of Optional<Subscriber> but I cant construct filter(o->o.isPresent) as it only "sees" the Subscriber.  Can you edify me?

Comment: The queris usually return Optional or Collection (a combination, i.e. a Collection of Optionals is odd).